# Cannot set a DataFrame with multiple columns to the single column total_servings

Tags: python, data-science

I am a beginner and getting familiar with pandas .
It is throwing an error , When I was trying to create a new column this way :

drinks['total_servings'] = drinks.loc[: ,'beer_servings':'wine_servings'].apply(calculate,axis=1)

Below is my code, and I get the following error for line number 9:

"`Cannot set a DataFrame with multiple columns to the single column total_servings`"

Any help or suggestion would be appreciated :)

```
import pandas as pd
drinks = pd.read_csv('drinks.csv')

def calculate(drinks):
    return drinks['beer_servings']+drinks['spirit_servings']+drinks['wine_servings']
print(drinks)
drinks['total_servings'] = drinks.loc[:, 'beer_servings':'wine_servings'].apply(calculate,axis=1)

drinks['beer_sales'] = drinks['beer_servings'].apply(lambda x: x*2)
drinks['spirit_sales'] = drinks['spirit_servings'].apply(lambda x: x*4)
drinks['wine_sales'] = drinks['wine_servings'].apply(lambda x: x*6)
drinks
```

Answer (score 3):

In your code, when function`calculate` is called with axis=1, it passes each row of the Dataframe as an argument. Here, the function `calculate` is returning dataframe with multiple columns but you are trying to assigned to a single column, which is not possible. You can try updating your code to this,

```
def calculate(each_row):
    return each_row['beer_servings'] + each_row['spirit_servings'] + each_row['wine_servings']

drinks['total_servings'] = drinks.apply(calculate, axis=1)
drinks['beer_sales'] = drinks['beer_servings'].apply(lambda x: x*2)
drinks['spirit_sales'] = drinks['spirit_servings'].apply(lambda x: x*4)
drinks['wine_sales'] = drinks['wine_servings'].apply(lambda x: x*6)

print(drinks)
```

Comment: Appreciate your effort ,thankyou , and I was able to solve it somehow with minor modifications .

Comment: @Bhargavi what were the modifications you did?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the reason is the wrong argument name inside `calculate` method. The given argument is `drink` but `drinks` used to calculate sum of columns.

The reason is `drink` is Series object that represents Row and sum of its elements is scalar. Meanwhile `drinks` is a DataFrame and sum of its columns will be a Series object

Sample code shows that this method works.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "A":[1,1,1,1,1], 
    "B":[2,2,2,2,2], 
    "C":[3,3,3,3,3]
})

def calculate(to_calc_df):
    return to_calc_df["A"] + to_calc_df["B"] +  to_calc_df["C"]
    
df["total"] = df.loc[:, "A":"C"].apply(calculate, axis=1)

print(df)
```

Result

```
   A  B  C  total
0  1  2  3      6
1  1  2  3      6
2  1  2  3      6
3  1  2  3      6
4  1  2  3      6
```

Comment: I am sorry about the "drinks"  in the argument but still it shows the same , but I will try your method, Thanks :)